# Python pandas function to concat into one row different values into one column based on repeating values in another

Tags: python, pandas

Apologies, I didn't even know how to title/describe the issue I am having, so bear with me. I have the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Invoice Number':[1279581, 1279581,1229422, 1229422, 1229422],
        'Project Key':[263736, 263736, 259661, 259661, 259661],
        'Project Type': ['Visibility', 'Culture', 'Spend', 'Visibility', 'Culture']}
df= pd.DataFrame(data)
```

[image]

How do I get the output to basically group the Invoice Numbers so that there is only 1 row per Invoice Number and combine the multiple Project Types (per that 1 Invoice) into 1 row? 
Code and output for output is below. 
Thanks much appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Invoice Number':[1279581,1229422],
        'Project Key':[263736, 259661],
        'Project Type': ['Visibility_Culture', 'Spend_Visibility_Culture']
}
output = pd.DataFrame(data)
output
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> (df
     .groupby(['Invoice Number', 'Project Key'])['Project Type']
     .apply(lambda x: '_'.join(x))
     .reset_index()
    )
   Invoice Number  Project Key              Project Type
0         1229422       259661  Spend_Visibility_Culture
1         1279581       263736        Visibility_Culture
```

Comment: One more question: What would be the best way to delimit for future searching? I just realized the Project Types are multiple words long. So instead of just Spend, and Visibility, and Culture, the Project Types would be: Spend Analytics & Manager Visibility & Team Culture

Comment: You should post a new question and link back to this one for reference.

Comment: @BrianBeing Seems to work fine as is, but you may want to consider a different delimiter, e.g. `', '`, `';'`, or `'/'`.

Comment: Is there a way to delimit by placing the value into quotations?

Comment: `', '.join([f"'{words}'" for words in x]))`