# Best way to concatenate strings with spaces in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Referring to this previous post:

[Python pandas function to concat into one row different values into one column based on repeating values in another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60230714/python-pandas-function-to-concat-into-one-row-different-values-into-one-column-b/60230784#60230784)

What would be the best way to delimit for future searching? I just realized the Project Types are multiple words long. So instead of just Spend, and Visibility, and Culture, the Project Types would be: Spend Analytics & Manager Visibility & Team Culture. For example: My first thought was to place each string value into quotes. Is this the best practices way when I'll have to filter later?

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'Invoice Number':[1279581,1229422],
        'Project Key':[263736, 259661],
        'Project Type': ['"Manager Visibility" "Team Culture"', '"Spend Analytics" "Manager Visibility" "Team Culture"']
}
output = pd.DataFrame(data)
output
```

Comment: Use a `str.join` where the `str` is a pattern that is never found in your strings. Something like `'||'` or `'**'` is probably safe (or perhaps just `' & '`)

Comment: best practice would be assign each one a key you could map back to using a dictionary to join your values. hard to say without knowing how the data ends up there in the first place